# Make MySQL ignore "The" from the start of a LIKE condition?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-like

I have a list of company names, and want to display all the names beginning with a certain character. `d` for example.

So the query is

```
SELECT * FROM company WHERE name LIKE 'd%'
```

But I also want the companies that start with "The" so

```
SELECT * FROM company WHERE name LIKE 'd%' OR name LIKE 'The d%'
```

But now the tricky bit when we get to 't' I want to remove all those that start with 'The'
while keeping others that begin with a 't' (and also keeping anything like 'The Truffle House' where the word *after* 'The' begins with a 't').

Any ideas? Would like to keep the logic in MySQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    company
WHERE   (name LIKE '?%' AND NOT name LIKE 'The %')
        OR name LIKE 'The ?%'
```

Comment: Pretty sure the OP was just using `d` as an example. They say it works for `d` and all other letters except for `t` where they want slightly different logic applied.

Comment: @Martin: replaced it with the question mark to avoid confusion

Comment: Sorry scrap that answer this is much better and cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM company WHERE name regexp '^(The)d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers I've just opted for this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    company
WHERE   (name LIKE '?%' AND NOT name LIKE 'The %')
        OR name LIKE 'The ?%'
```

for `t` I've just done a long list of `NOT LIKE` so

`AND (company_name LIKE 'The%t' OR company_name LIKE 't%') AND company_name NOT LIKE 'The a%' AND company_name NOT LIKE 'The b%'` etc....